# Improve the JWT Exception handling in json format data

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi i am currently having a problem about JWT Exception JSON Message. The problem is when i checkIn but my token is expired and i received this

```
"message": "Token has expired",
    "exception": "Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Exceptions\\TokenExpiredException",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\Snowfox1991\\Desktop\\Capstone project\\back-end\\back-end\\vendor\\tymon\\jwt-auth\\src\\Claims\\Expiration.php",
    "line": 31,
```

But when i write the getAuthUser() in APIController, i use try catch this one

```
public function getAuthUser(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'token' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = JWTAuth::authenticate($request->token);

    try {

        if (!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Token has expired'
        ], $e->getStatusCode()

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Token is invalid'
        ], $e->getStatusCode()

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Token is absent'
        ], $e->getStatusCode()

    // }

    return response()->json(['user' => $user]);
}
```

And it still return the same as the original without the json format. Can i ask how to improve this exception using json format without handling the error like this. Thank you

Comment: Is that code in a namespace? Then you need to prefix the exceptions with a backslash:  `\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException` or PHP will assume that the namespace you wrote is under your current namespace. Better yet, before you class, add the exceptions using `use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;` and simply do: `catch (TokenExpiredException $e)` and so on for the other exceptions as well.

Comment: That code is when i getAuthUser(), and i use try catch to retrun json format error. But i have tried that one and still got 500 and error like original

Comment: If that wasn't the issue, then you need to show us more of your code. Just showing the `catch()` statements isn't enough for us to go on.

Comment: when i check on github the return error, they said update in Handle.php but when i update, the message is empty without any message in json format. so weird

Comment: Well, as I said, without seeing more of your code, any answer/suggestion would just be simple guesses. Show us _all_ the relevant code (including your attempt with correct namespaces) and we might be able to help.

Comment: okay i will update my code now

Comment: i have updated my code about the getAuthUser() and try catch exception